# Close command prompt after executing MSI install from Batch File

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, windows-installer

I am currently doing an MSI install and using a batch file to execute the MSI with defaultsini and installdir. It is a /qb! install so that it cannot be cancelled as it's meant to be deployable, however the command prompt stays open and it looks slightly unprofessional.

Is there a way to have command prompt launch the MSI with custom settings and then close while the install happens?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you launch the _MSI_? `start "" <msi line here>`  should launch it asynchronously…

Comment: That worked, thank you very much.